# Prometheus Deployer properties for Scrape

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I noticed that my app running in Kubernetes doesn't actually get registered in grafana unless I add the following deployer properties:

`deployer.*.kubernetes.podAnnotations=prometheus.io/path:/actuator/prometheus,prometheus.io/port:8080,prometheus.io/scrape:true`

Is that supposed to be the case? If so, how can I add add these deployer properties to always be there for every deployment without having to manually add it in the `Freetext` section before deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! That helped me track down the answer. I tried putting those properties in (and I might have messed up putting them in) but they kept showing up as `app` properties and not deployer properties. Then I tried something very similar in the skipper config:

```
data:
  application.yaml: |-
    spring:
      cloud:
        skipper:
          server:
            platform:
              kubernetes:
                accounts:
                  default:
                    podAnnotations: 'prometheus.io/path:/actuator/prometheus,prometheus.io/port:8080,prometheus.io/scrape:true'
                    ...
```

And it worked beautifully. Sabby, thanks again!

Comment: Now when I reread the description, I was wrong in pointing to "global" properties. What I pointed out is indeed the mechanism to supply global "application" level properties. Think of the requirement to supply Kafka creds to all the apps, which is when this would be useful. What you did to supply `podAnnotations` in Skipper is absolutely the right thing to do in this scenario. Nicely done!

Answer (score 0):

What you're attempting to accomplish can be solved with the help of "global" property configuration in SCDF.

See: [Common Application Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-global-properties)

However, please note that this method will apply the desired configurations to *every* stream application that SCDF deploys on the targeted platform. IMO, it is a valid use of it since you'd need metrics scraping for all the deployed apps anyway.

Also, as a FYI, a similar property is available for Task apps.

Comment: Thank you! That helped me track down the answer. I tried putting those properties in (and I might have messed up putting them in) but they kept showing up as app properties and not deployer properties. Then I tried something very similar in the skipper config and it worked. I'll add that to the answer at the bottom for anyone else. Thank you again, this really helped!